# PayPal REST API through PHP SDK return "Incoming JSON request does not map to API request"

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal, sdk

I'm trying to create and execute a payment with PayPal REST API through PHP SDK (sandbox environment) like showing below. The payment creation (`$payment->create`) work fine but the payment execution (`$payment->execute`) return `"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request"`.
The JSON request is created by the SDK, then what can be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

```
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

$item = new Item();
$item->setName('Any name')
     ->setCurrency('EUR')
     ->setQuantity(1)
     ->setPrice(0.99);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item));

$details = new Details();
$details->setTax(0)
        ->setSubtotal(0.99);

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('EUR')
       ->setTotal(0.99)
       ->setDetails($details);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setDescription('Any description')
            ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(BASE_URL.'/payment/?success=true')
             ->setCancelUrl(BASE_URL.'/payment/?success=false');

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);

    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    //Function for extract the error message,
    //the error message can be showing with
    //a simple var_dump($ex)
    $exception = self::getException($ex); 
}
```

Comment: A quick search on Google showed me that this error is usually caused by the json that you are sending being invalid. Make sure you have read the documentation and that everything you have put is what they expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was enough put

```
$payment->setIntent('authorize')
```

instead of

```
$payment->setIntent('sale')
```

and eliminate the execution

```
$execution = new PaymentExecution(); $result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
```

Then, after

```
$payment->create
```

I used the "href" from

```
$payment->links
```

to do the redirect. Everything went perfectly. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Am not a PHP dev (.Net), so based on reading the above, check into this section in your code:

```
$execution = new PaymentExecution();
$result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
```

You are sending a *new*  `PaymentExecution` *without*  the `payer_id` and the `Payment.Id` which you would obtain *after* the user approves your `paypal` Payment request that you created.

That said, I don't see that part (though as above, not a PHP dev) so I could be wrong. The steps are:

1. Create the Payment
2. Go into the Approval Flow -> user is redirected to Paypal and approves the Payment you created in #1 -> and is redirected back to your site (the returnUrl)

   a. the `PayerID` will be in the querystring in this process

   b. the `paymentId` will also be in the querystring in this process
3. **After the user is redirected back to your site from PayPal (your `returnUrl`)** - `Execute` a new `Payment`, set it's `id` to the one you obtained  (#2b), sending the `PaymentExecution` with its `PayerID` set to the what you you obtained (#2a)

In c# (you'll need to convert this to PHP):

```
    var _payment = new Payment { id = the_payment_id_you_obtained };
    var _payExec = new PaymentExecution { payer_id = the_payer_id_you_obtained };

    var _response = _payment.Execute(context, _payExec);
```

Hth...

Comment: Yes, surely that's the problem, it lacks the approval of the payment. Thank You!