# Paypal: PHP SDK Error Incoming JSON request does not map to API request

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, payment-gateway, payment-method

I'm using PHP Paypal SDK: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

Referred [PayPal REST API through PHP SDK return "Incoming JSON request does not map to API request"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920493/paypal-rest-api-through-php-sdk-return-incoming-json-request-does-not-map-to-ap)

In continue with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827032/paypal-how-to-get-payment-id-on-basis-of-transaction-id

**On basis of already available Transaction Id, Need to get Payment Id**

I have tried below code

```
require __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php';

use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\CreditCard;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\FundingInstrument;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
// Extra Code
use PayPal\Api\PaymentDetail;

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$transaction = new PaymentDetail(
        '{
          "method" : "CASH",
          "date" : "2014-07-06 03:30:00 PST",
          "note" : "Cash received."
        }'
);

$transaction->setTransactionId("3NT32794KF4824703");

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

// For Sample Purposes Only.
$request = clone $payment;

try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);
} catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getData();
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($payment);
exit;
```

When i run above code it gives below kind of error

```
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"aa8bfa2a41f1f"}

PayPal\Api\Payment Object
(
    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
        (
            [intent] => sale
            [payer] => PayPal\Api\Payer Object
                (
                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                        (
                            [payment_method] => paypal
                        )

                )

            [transactions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PayPal\Api\PaymentDetail Object
                        (
                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [method] => CASH
                                    [date] => 2014-07-06 03:30:00 PST
                                    [note] => Cash received.
                                    [transaction_id] => 3NT32794KF4824703
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How to solve above error? Please guide

Response from **Paypal Tech Support**

> After discussion and testing with the dev teams, they confirmed that
> you can't use TransactionId to retrieve the PaymentId. PaymentId is
> generated upon initial REST API call. And this happen to REST API
> only.
>
> Transaction id can be generated after REST API execute payment,
> Classic API [NVP/SOAP] DoEC API or normal button payment completion.
> It will never work to reverse the search to find the Payment Id.
>
> As for now, the only workaround for you is to log each of the REST API
> request regardless if it failed or not to trace the PaymentId.

**Need to Achieve: Once payment is done, it will be keep on hold. After X days it will be processed. When processed Amount will be deducted from Customer's Account.**

Comment: So what is the content of the incoming JSON Request ?

Answer (score 0):

First you make payment create request with

```
$payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent("sale")
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));    
$payment->create($apiContext);
```

1. In create response you will get "apporval url", this approval url used to user pay there payment.
2. Then you will receive notification from paypal via what url send in "$redirectUrls" .
3. Here u will get "Payment id" and "payer id" using that make execute payment.

   ```
   $execution = new PaymentExecution();
   $execution->setPayerId($da['PayerID']);
   $apiContext=$this->apicontext();
   $res = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
   ```

Comment: Hi @Akagesab thanks for response. Do we code available for this to Download?

Comment: Get Api context:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/bootstrap.php

Create Request:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePayment.php

Response handling: 
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/ExecutePayment.php