# Incoming JSON request does not map to API request"

Tags: paypal

I am getting an error when trying to create a payment, the error I am getting is:

> -url: "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment"   -data:
>   "{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not
>   map to API
>   request","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/doc
>   ▶"   #message: "Got Http response code 400 when accessing
>   https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment."

I am trying to create payments like so, by adding it to a list and then added it to the transaction

```
    // type of paypal payment (redirect)
    $payer = PayPal::Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

    // iniate the item
    $item = Paypal::item();

    // iniate the ammount
    $amount = PayPal:: Amount();

    switch($type)
    {            
        case 'job':
            $item
                ->setName('Job advertisement on '. Config('app.name'))
                ->setDescription('Job advertisement on '. Config('app.name'))
                ->setCurrency('GBP')
                ->setQuantity(1)
                ->setTax(0.2)
                ->setPrice(Config('settings.job_price'));

            $details = Paypal::Details();
            $details->setShipping(1.2)
                ->setTax(1.3)
                ->setSubtotal(17.50);

            $amount->setCurrency('GBP')
                ->setDetails($details)
                ->setTotal(Config('settings.job_price'));
        break;
        case 'course':   
            $item
                ->setName('Course advertisement on '. Config('app.name'))
                ->setDescription('Course advertisement on '. Config('app.name'))
                ->setCurrency('GBP')
                ->setQuantity(1)
                ->setTax(0.2)
                ->setPrice(Config('settings.course_price'));

            $details = Paypal::Details();
            $details->setShipping(1.2)
                ->setTax(1.3)
                ->setSubtotal(17.50);

            $amount->setCurrency('GBP')
                ->setDetails($details)
                ->setTotal(Config('settings.course_price'));
        break;
    }

    // geerate the item list
    $itemList = Paypal::itemList();
    $itemList->setItems($item);

    // now create the transactions
    $transaction = Paypal::transaction();
    $transaction
        ->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($itemList)
        ->setDescription("Payment description")
        ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

    // setup the redirect uri's'
    $redirectUrls = PayPal:: RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls
        ->setReturnUrl(route('payment.complete'))
        ->setCancelUrl(route('payment.cancelled'));

    // set up the person's information
    $payment = PayPal::Payment();
    $payment
        ->setIntent('authorize')
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions([$transaction]);
    print_r($payment);
    try{
        dd($payment->create($this->_apiContext));
        $response = $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
    } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
       dd($ex);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        die($ex);
    }
    $redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;

    // redirect to paypal for payment
    return Redirect::to( $redirectUrl );
```

The data being sent is like so:

```
PayPal\Api\Payment Object ( 
    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( 
        [intent] => authorize [payer] => PayPal\Api\Payer Object ( 
            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( 
                [payment_method] => paypal 
            ) 
        ) 
        [redirect_urls] => PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls Object ( 
            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( 
                [return_url] => http://localhost/payment/payment-done 
                [cancel_url] => http://localhost/payment/payment-cancelled 
            ) 
        ) 
        [transactions] => Array ( 
            [0] => PayPal\Api\Transaction Object ( 
                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( 
                    [amount] => PayPal\Api\Amount Object ( 
                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( 
                            [currency] => GBP 
                            [details] => PayPal\Api\Details Object ( 
                                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( 
                                    [shipping] => 1.20 
                                    [tax] => 1.30 
                                    [subtotal] => 17.50 
                                ) 
                            ) 
                            [total] => 125 
                        ) 
                    ) 
                    [item_list] => PayPal\Api\ItemList Object ( 
                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( 
                            [items] => PayPal\Api\Item Object ( 
                                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( 
                                    [name] => Job advertisement on Laravel 
                                    [description] => Job advertisement on Laravel 
                                    [currency] => GBP 
                                    [quantity] => 1 
                                    [tax] => 0.20 
                                    [price] => 125 
                                ) 
                            ) 
                        ) 
                    ) 
                    [description] => Payment description 
                    [invoice_number] => 599cd8d03b626 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you show us your generated json string?

Answer (score 7):

It was enough put

```
$payment->setIntent('authorize')
```

Instead of

```
$payment->setIntent('sale')
```

and eliminate the execution

```
 $execution = new PaymentExecution(); $result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
```

Then, after

```
$payment->create
```

I used the "href" from

```
$payment->links
```

to do the redirect. Everything went perfectly

[Incoming JSON request does not map to API request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920493/paypal-rest-api-through-php-sdk-return-incoming-json-request-does-not-map-to-ap)

Answer (score 4):

Change below code

$transaction->setAmount(Config('settings.job_price'))

to

```
$amount =   new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD')  // set to your currency
        ->setTotal($total);

$transaction->setAmount($amount)
```

I think, parameter of setAmount must be member of Class Amount.

Answer (score 0):

#### Learn more about this issue;

Visit [Paypal Git](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/issues/190) where this issue was reported and patch provided.

Answer (score 0):

In My case i my using laravel 
I was calling this script from another function then its show same error. 
When i call this function direct post method . it was fix.